Open sub tree in Catia
I want to Open Sub Tree in Catia using Vba. Does it possible?
I try CATIA.StartCommand "Open Sub Tree" but nothing happen. I also try to find it in the command list but there is no Open Sub Tree but if I right click on the part its still have.
Thank you very much for all the support

I solved this problem using WINAPI to manipulate the mouse to show the contextual menu of the feature and open the sub-tree from there.
My algorithm for opening is: Select the item in the tree (so it is orange), to a StartCommand("Center Graph") to position the feature in the tree in the center of the screeen, Take a screen shot of the middle left of the screen, search  pixels to find where  the orange area is. Move the mouse over orange pixels and perform a right mouse down, right mouse up (to display the context menu) and send an "n" character to open the sub tree.
Good luck.
